# Re-using SSH keys?

Tags: ssh

I'm now up to 4 SD cards with various version of Raspbian (Adafruit, Raspbian, Xbian, Raspbian Stripped Server), and I'm finding it annoying when I go to fool with another version that I have to edit my known_hosts file each time because each SD card has its own key.

I'm thinking there is no particular reason not to simply overwrite the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub in /root/.ssh/ with the same files on each card so that all of the cards match?

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean when sshing *into* the RPi?
In that case you need to copy the files in `/etc/ssh`.

I don't see any problem with doing that. The primary reason for those keys is to prove that the machine you think you are logging into *is* the machine you are logging into.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with overriding both server files (in /etc/ssh, like server key files) and client files (in your home directory ~/.ssh). You should however remember (in case you would copy whole directory or use some way of copying that won't preserve permissions) to set proper file/directories permissions (they should be the same as before copying). SSH may refuse to work when you have too broad file permissions (for your security).

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your ~/.ssh/config file on the client to not do the host key checking:

```
Host 1.2.3.4
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Replace 1.2.3.4 with the IP address of the RPi.
This tells ssh to record the host key in /dev/null and to not ask about changed or missing host keys.

Of course has security implications so do this at your own risk.

Comment: You could but crippling host authentication for every system you connect to is far worse than using the same host keys on multiple systems all of which you trust.